# HTML5: using manifest fallback to check user's connectivity

Tags: html, connection, manifest, fallback, offlineapps

I'm focusing on offline web applications with HTML5 at the moment. I came to the point where I need a reliable method of checking the user's connection to determine whether he/she is online or offline at the moment. Since I learned that the navigator.onLine property is highly unreliable I found a very nice method using the Fallback area of the cache manifest. I implemented two similar solutions from two different books, one being "Introducing HTML5" (Lawson/Sharp) and one "HTML5: The Missing Manual" (MacDonald). I guess this is an issue of HTTP caching (I use Apache and localhost), which I don't really know too much about. I pasted my code, it's a few files, but very little code.

The adapted solution from Introducing HTML5:
http://pastebin.com/UGsmnAtK

The adapted solution from HTML5 - the missing manual:
http://pastebin.com/8v5ck3E6

Tested with Chrome 16...

=== What I want ===

- start app with empty cache and running apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown
- stop apache
- click the button -> alert "Offline" is shown
- start apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown

=== What happens ===

Introducing HTML5 solution:
- start app with empty cache and running apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown
- stop apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown
- start apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown

HTML5: the missing manual solution:
- start app with empty cache and running apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown
- stop apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown
- start apache
- click the button -> alert "Online" is shown

Other scenarios and use cases fail in similar fashion. The books promise that you can check the user's connectivity any time using their methods. So I guess I'm doing something wrong here. I would thankfully embrace any ideas on this topic.

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the online.js is loaded when you click the button with the Introducing HTML5 or when the page is loaded with the HTML5 - the missing manual code and the site is available through Apache. Next time the scripts isn't loaded as it is already in the browser cache.

The coce from [Introducing HTML5](http://pastebin.com/UGsmnAtK) looks like it should work if you add a random value to the script URL. Something like:

```
function testOnline(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'online.js?r=' + Math.random();

    window.setOnline = function(online) {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        fn(online);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Hi Maurice, thank you very much for your answer, you really helped me a lot! I just tried to add the query string and it really works! Every click on the button invokes a GET request on 'online.js'. Maybe I should generally learn more about all these Apache techniques. First post on stackoverflow, immediate success! Cheers, Felix

Comment: Hi Felix, Nothing specific Apache about this, I just changed the URL slightly to avoid the online.js being cached by the browser. Please accept as answer to help others who run into this issue.